# Ubuntu insists on installing a broken package

Tags: virtualbox, update-manager, crash

Everytime I boot the system, I receive a "System crash" message and here is the details:

[image]

This package is already removed, but Ubuntu insists on trying to install it everytime I boot the system. The Virtualbox package available in the repositories (v. 4) didn't work for me, so I removed all packages from Virtualbox, then I installed the .deb file from Virtualbox's site (v. 5) and everything is working just fine. BUT, ubuntu instists on installing virtualbox-dkms package from the repositories, I don't know why. Here is some additional information:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep virtualbox && dkms status
ii  virtualbox-5.0                              5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty              amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.19.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-346, 346.82, 3.19.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
vboxhost, 5.0.2, 3.19.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

What's going on exactly and how do I fix this error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox && dkms status` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Answer updated

Comment: @Pilot6 I've added the information you asked to the post, thanks.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Output for this command shows no errors. But the problem was fixed by @Pilot6 answer. Thanks you guys for your time (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have removed that virtualbox-dkms 4.3.10 package.

It had problems and apport tries to report them.

The easiest way to solve it is not to close this error window every time you boot, but uncheck "Send an error report" and press "Continue".

After that apport should not pop up again with that error message.

Comment: Ok, understand =)